# read custom userdata in jqGrid

Tags: jqgrid

I already did much research and tried a lot, but didn't yet solve the following problem:

The objective is to set a specific font color for some rows if a condition is true.
The data for the condition is not dispayed in the grid.

my idea: 
I made a custom userdata like that:

```
"userdata":{
"PROCESSED_TIME":"00:02.250"
,"rows":[
   {"id":"4711","status":"1"}, 
   {"id":"4712","status":"0"},
   {"id":"4713","status":"1"}
]}
```

How can I read the status now for example in "afterInsertRow" event to color the font if status is 0? Processed time i alread arrived with the following command:

```
$("#MyGrid").getGridParam('userData').PROCESSED_TIME
```

You don't need to explain how to set the color of a row, but just how to access the status value.

Maybe using the userdata in this case is also the wrong way ?

Comment: For clarification, the data from the condition is returned along the other grid columns but it is hidden or is other the source for get it? If the last is the case can you be more specific?

Comment: Do you load data from the server? Do you fill the `userdata` on the server? Why you not just place the list of ids in the `userdata`? In the case you will don't need to enumerate *all* rows locally and to test the data. JavaScript is much much slowly as native SQL code or any other native code. So the detection of ids of the rows which has  the specified condition will be better to do **on the server**.

Comment: I also have an additional array in "rows" with all the data to display in the grid.  All the data is filled on the Server. And with jquery i want to read the status value and change the color of the row. @Oleg you would work with a new separate array in the userdata for example with all the rowid's to be colored ? like "INACTIVE_ROWS" .Example:  "userdata":{"PROCESSED_TIME":"00:02.250","INACTIVE_ROWS":"[{"4712","4718"}],[...]}

Answer (score 0):

After the hint of Oleg I found the solution. 
Instead of putting the status in the "rows" element of the userdata, I saved it as a string in a separate variable. My userdata now looks like this:

```
"userdata":{
"PROCESSED_TIME":"00:02.250",
"INAKTIVE_ROWS":"4711,4713"
,"rows":[
{"id":"4711"}, 
{"id":"4712"},
{"id":"4713"}
]}
```

In the "loadComplete" event I read the string and set the color for the inactive rows like that:

```
var inactiveRowstring = $("#MyGrid").getGridParam('userData').inactiveRows;

if (inactiveRowstring!=undefined){
 var rows = inactiveRowstring.split(',');
 for (var i=0; i<rows.length; i++){     
   var trElement = $('tr[id="'+rows[i]+'"]');
   trElement.removeClass('ui-widget-content');
   trElement.addClass('ui-widget-content-inactive');
 }
}
```

Thanks for your help!